# The success of the European Union policy response to migration waves from the Middle East and Africa

Tags: european-union, immigration, asylum

Did the European Union policy response to the large-scale movement of people from the Middle East and Africa introduce pull-factors that encouraged new and/or continued movements from these regions?

Comment: Questions which say "could be seen" aren't normally a brilliant fit for this site. There are people for whom not shelling migrant ships is too much encouragement, and there are people who think handing every person that lands 10,000€ at the beach wouldn't be a pull factor.

Comment: Applications for asylum in the EU have declined in both 2016 and 2017. "large-scale movement of people from ... Africa" to Europe has been occurring for at least well over a thousand years. Policy cannot stop the migration of people from one place to another on this planet. See also [Migrant from Africa to Europe by sea from North Africa](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8085/21216)

Comment: @guest271314 Policy most certainly **can** stop - or at least significantly decrease - the migration of people from one place to another on this planet. Mexico has done pretty well reducing immigration, with policies far more draconian than USAs. USSR had virtually no illegal immigration. Neither does Saudi Arabia.

Comment: @user4012 Certainly not as a piece of paper alone. By the time a formal "policy" is drafted people have largely already moved. No policy to restrict European colonization by native peoples stopped Europeans from slaughtering entire populations during the course several hundred years. Some have asked what the European response to the "Trail of Tears" was: millions of Europeans getting the hell out of Europe "settling" in lands where the "Indian Removal" policy was implemented. Policy can be effective when the goal is to colonize, to reduce the infidel to perpetual servitude, e.g., Dum Diversas.

Comment: @user4012 See the graphs for "Hispanic Population in the United 
States: 1970 to 2050" at [Hispanics 
in the United States (2006)](https://www.census.gov/population/www/socdemo/files/Internet_Hispanic_in_US_2006.pdf); [It’s Official: Latino Population Now Equals That of Whites in California (2013)](https://abcnews.go.com/ABC_Univision/latino-population-now-equals-whites-california/story?id=19555998); [The US will become ‘minority white’ in 2045, Census projects (2018)](https://www.brookings.edu/blog/the-avenue/2018/03/14/the-us-will-become-minority-white-in-2045-census-projects/)

Comment: @guest271314 - US never had such a policy. I'd argue, even on paper.

Comment: @user4012 Which policy are you referring to? Restricting certain individuals that the U.S. classified as being within a certain group from immigrating to the U.S.; removal by force of certain groups the U.S. classified as being fit for removal from their land; or other policy?

Comment: @guest271314 - the main one would be punishing companies and individuals for employing illegal aliens

Comment: @user4012 Not following what you mean?

Comment: @user4012 _“By greatly slashing the number of Hispanic and black African immigrants entering America...” said Michael Clemens, an economist at the Center for Global Development, a think tank that has been critical of the proposal. “Selectively blocking immigrant groups changes who America is. This is the biggest attempt in a century to do that.”_ [Trump immigration plan could keep whites in U.S. majority for up to five more years](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2018/02/06/trump-immigration-plan-could-keep-whites-in-u-s-majority-for-up-to-five-more-years/)

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is, yes. I'm not even going to argue that the Western countries caused that very wave of migration with actions such as the invasion of Iraq or the support for the "arab spring" movement (that began the civil wars that caused a lot of those migrations), or the completely unjustified action against Khaddafi that transformed Lybia from a stable country to a hive of terrorists and slave traders. But yes, most "refugee boats" leave Africa from Lybia now.

Comment: Thank you. But what _were_ those pull-factor policies?

Comment: @Ben _"The right to asylum **shall** be guaranteed with due respect for the rules of the Geneva Convention of 28 July 1951 and the Protocol of 31 January 1967 relating to the status of refugees and in accordance with the Treaty on European Union and the Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union. (hereinafter referred to as "the Treaties")."_ (emphasis added) [EU Charter of Fundamental Rights - Article 18 - Right to asylum](http://fra.europa.eu/en/charterpedia/article/18-right-asylum)

Comment: But does that not simply encode the Geneva Convention in EU rules, or does it extend it somehow?

Comment: @Ben _"This **policy** must be consistent with the Geneva Convention
of 28 July 1951 and the Protocol thereto of 31 January 1967. Neither the TFEU nor the Charter provides a definition of the terms ‘asylum’ or ‘refugee’, but both refer explicitly to the Geneva Convention and its Protocol."_ (emphasis added) [Migration and Asylum:
a challenge for Europe (Source: European Parliament)](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/RegData/etudes/PERI/2017/600414/IPOL_PERI(2017)600414_EN.pdf). The EU is party to specific treaties. What do you mean by "extend"?

Comment: @Ben  Are you trying to determine if a "policy" of a government can halt human migration? In general, laws and administrative regulations occur _after_ events have occurred; and lag behind human activities which prompted the legislation or administrative regulations.

Comment: No. I am asking whether the EU has gone over and above the obligations that pre-existed, resulting in additional migratory pull factors.

Comment: @Ben: I would say that those pull-factor policies could be split between official and unofficial. Officially, you have the fact that countries like Germany not only accepted every asylum request, even in cases where there were no documents and it was impossible to determine the origin of the migrant, but actually made it mandatory that all European countries accepted refugees, even countries to where those refugees weren't going to. Unofficially, you have the fact that multiple European politicians publicly stated multiple times that "Europe needs migrants to deal with declining demographics".

Comment: Thank you. Do have a link or reference to the “mandatory acceptance” of these arrivals?

Comment: I removed a paragraph from this answer which wasn't addressing the question and seemed primarily to spread a political agenda. Please note that answers should answer the question, nothing more and nothing less. We are here to explain politics, not spread political opinions.

Comment: @Philipp How does an edit that removes 15 sources help in making my answer more objective and less of an opinion? "Spreading a political agenda"? You literally removed 15 (fifteen) sources that supported what I stated in the paragraph you still left untouched. How is that "not addressing the question"?

Answer (score 4):

It would be a mistake to think of one "wave" of migrants. There are **different groups** with different pull and push factors.

- Civil war refugees from Syria and Iraq. Many stayed in the region until the international community [slashed aid to the camps](http://www.unhcr.org/news/latest/2015/6/558acbbc6/funding-shortage-leaves-syrian-refugees-danger-missing-vital-support.html). These people were willing to risk death to get away from where they were because staying would mean slow death. Clearly push factors.
- Civil war refugees from places like Afghanistan or Somalia. Probably many of them were not aware that getting to Europe was feasible before 2015, so there might have been pull factors here. But objectively, they had every reason to leave and if Europe lived up to its ideals they should get refugee status.
- Economic refugees from extreme poverty and violence in central Africa. Same as for the refugees from Afghanistan. In previous decades many died in their home countries instead of marching north.
- Economic migrants from relative poverty and political oppression in northern Africa. They could survive where they are, it just wouldn't be a good life. The asylum policies may be pull factors here.
- Economic migrants from within Europe, e.g. from Albania and Kosovo. Not many people talk about them, but look at the EU refugee statistics from 2015 and before. A change in regulations slashed refugee numbers since then.